# Change URL in address bar but keep on same page

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Is it possible to rewrite a url so that the page stays the same and the url itself is chanaged ?

E.G.:

I have a page at www.example.com/sales

I want this url to appear in the address bar as www.example.com/sales_and_repairs

I am NOT trying to redirect a page at www.example.com/sales to ANOTHER page at www.example.com/sales_and_repairs ....There is only ONE page - it is just the URL I am trying to change so that if a person types in www.example.com/sales, they will go to that page but the URL in the Address bar will change to show as www.example.com/sales_and_repairs

Is this possible with rewrite rules ?  Anytjhing I have looked up appears to suggest that you have to be redirecting to a second page - but that is not what I want to do - I just want to change the actual URL.

Any advice please ??

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect www.example.com/sales_and_repairs to www.example.com/sales permanently you can do it with an .htaccess file.

First of all, you'll have to enable mod_rewrite in apache.

Then add the following to your .htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^http://www\.example\.com/sales_and_repairs$ http://www\.example\.com/sales [R=301,NC,L]
```

This method allow you to have only one file behind the two urls.

However if you want to modify the url after a user's action, you can do it with the answer given by Sparda above.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can achieve this with javascript :

```
location.hash = 'newurl';
```

But this will add an anchor to the url.
Some earlier features of html5 can do this but are not really supported yet :

```
history.pushState(data, 'title', 'newurl');
```